# How to build sonarscanner ,getting "MSbuild.exe is not recognize as internal and external command"?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, code-analysis, sonarqube-scan, msbuild-4.0

I have installed Msbuild along with studio2017 but while building sonarscanner the msbuild.exe not found error thrown.

Comment: I know this is not the same question, but maybe it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53509209/4944847 (read the comments)

Comment: The solution is here: [How to build With sonarscanner ,getting “MSbuild.exe is not recognize as internal and external command”?](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-build-with-sonarscanner-getting-msbuild-exe-is-not-recognize-as-internal-and-external-command/4619?u=agabrys)

Comment: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-build-with-sonarscanner-getting-msbuild-exe-is-not-recognize-as-internal-and-external-command/4619 
This question posted by me on sonarqube community . Thanks by the way